# Geoserver - gsconfig set style for a ambiguous layer name

Tags: styles, layer, geoserver

In my geoserver i have layers with the same name in different workspaces. How can i **get_layer** from the specific layer of an workspace. example:

```
Workspace| Store | Layer
Wa       | DSa   | myLayer
Wb       | DSb   | myLayer
```

using **get_resource** i can distinguish which layer im talking about..

resouce = cat.get_resource(myLayer, store="DSa", workspace="Wa")

but i don't know how can i give to that layer a specific style.

In other hand when i do:

layer = cat.get_layer(myLayer)

i will allways get the first. The problem for me is how can i give a style for each layer.

layer._set_default_style("my_style_name")

In this case how do you set a style for myLayer of Wb and other style for Wa??

Answer (score 0):

The solution it seems to be to use `layer = cat.get_layer("Wa:myLayer")`. I hope to help someone with the same issue.